# use SnapKit make constraint to a UIView but show nothing

Tags: swift, snapkit

At a full clear new swift project from "Single View App" template.
When I ensure SnapKit can be import correctly.
I just play very simple code to show a Rectangle:

```
    let test = UIView()
    test.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    test.frame.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 300)
    
    self.view.addSubview(test)
    test.snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
        // maker.top.equalTo(30)
        // maker.centerX.equalTo(self.view)
        // maker.height.equalTo(100)
    }
```

put this code into func viewDidLoad of "UIViewController.swift" .
from now, SnapKit things is commented, and it's work FINE! like picture showing:
[work fine snap(use frame.size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H81kn.jpg)
But when I uncomment SnapKit things, it's display Nothing! like this:
[work bad snap(use SnapKit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhhkW.jpg)

So,Please help me find the trouble,thank you!

Comment: I usually hate the kind of comment I'm about to give right now (one that doesn't answer the question but instead makes an unwanted opinion-based observation) but I hope it will help you as a developer. Why would you use a 3rd-party API for something as simple and basic as constraints? You really should use 3rd-party APIs when you basically sort of kind of have to, like Google Maps... again, in my opinion. 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set frame size, if you using constraints.

This how your code should look like:

```
    let test = UIView()
    test.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    self.view.addSubview(test)
    test.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(30)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(300)
        make.width.equalTo(500)
    }
```

Comment: Try adding some code to your answer to help with clarity.